# Unable to finish the spark job on spark standalone cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm a very novice to spark, been on spark for just a week. This is my code in pyspark, running on standalone spark cluster with a single master and two slaves. Trying to run a job spark reading a 01. million record data and performing some manipulation on the data then dumping the dataframe on oracle table.Im having trouble completing the job. Its seems like this program as created 404 partitions to complete the tasks. On the console or terminal I can see 403/404 are completed but the last and final task on the partition 404 is taking forever to complete the job. I'm unable to complete the job. can anyone tell me the issue with my code. can anyone help with optimizing the performance on spark or can point me to a guide or something? Any tut or guide would help. Thanks in advance

```
# creating a spark session
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("pyspark_testing_29012020") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

# target table schema and column order
df_target = spark.read.csv("mycsv path", header = True)
df_local_schema = df_target.schema
df_column_order = df_target.columns

# dataframe with input file/dataset values and schema
df_source = spark.read\
    .format("csv")\
    .option("header", "false")\
    .option("inferschema", "true")\
    .option("delimiter", ",")\
    .schema(df_local_schema)\
    .load("csv path")


# dataframe with the target file/dataset values
df_target = spark.read\
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:system/oracle123@127.0.0.1:0101:orcl") \
    .option("dbtable", "mydata") \
    .option("user", "system") \
    .option("password", "oracle123") \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")\
    .load()


# splitting the target table in to upper and lower sections
df_target_upper = df_target.where(df_target['Key'] < 5) # set A
df_source_upper = df_source.where(df_source['Key'] < 5) # set B
df_source_lower = df_source.where(df_source['Key'] > 4) # set D
df_target_lower = df_target.where(df_target['key'] > 4) # set C


''' now programming for the upper segment of the data '''

# set operation A-B
A_minus_B = df_target_upper.join(df_source_upper,
                                 on=['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4'],
                                 how='left_anti')
A_minus_B = A_minus_B.select(sorted(df_column_order))


# set operation B-A
B_minus_A = df_source_upper.join(df_target_upper,
                                 on=['key1', 'key2','key3','key4'],how = 'left_anti')
B_minus_A = B_minus_A.select(sorted(df_column_order))


# union of A-B and B-A
AmB_union_BmA = A_minus_B.union(B_minus_A)
AmB_union_BmA = AmB_union_BmA.select(sorted(df_column_order))

# A-B left anti B-A to get the uncommon record in both the dataframes
new_df = A_minus_B.join(B_minus_A, on=['key'], how = 'left_anti')
new_df = new_df.select(sorted(df_column_order))

AmB_union_BmA = AmB_union_BmA.select(sorted(df_column_order))

AnB = df_target_upper.join(df_source_upper,
                           on=['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4'],
                           how='inner')

df_AnB_without_dupes = dropDupeDfCols(AnB)
new_AnB = df_AnB_without_dupes.select(sorted(df_column_order))


final_df = AmB_union_BmA.union(new_AnB)
final_df.show()
result_df = B_minus_A.union(new_df)

df_result_upper_seg = result_df.union(new_AnB)



''' now programming for the lower segment of the data '''

# set operation C-D
C_minus_D = df_target_lower.join(df_source_lower, on=['key'], how='left_anti')
C_minus_D = C_minus_D.select(sorted(df_column_order))


# set operation D-C
D_minus_C = df_source_lower.join(df_target_lower, on=['key'], how = 'left_anti')
D_minus_C = D_minus_C.select(sorted(df_column_order))


# union of C-D union D-C
CmD_union_DmC = C_minus_D.union(D_minus_C)
CmD_union_DmC = CmD_union_DmC.select(sorted(df_column_order))


# C-D left anti D-C to get the uncommon record in both the dataframes
lower_new_df = C_minus_D.join(D_minus_C, on=['key'], how = 'left_anti')
lower_new_df = lower_new_df.select(sorted(df_column_order))


CmD_union_DmC = CmD_union_DmC.select(sorted(df_column_order))

CnD = df_target_lower.join(df_source_lower,
                           on=['key'], how='inner')


new_CnD = dropDupeDfCols(CnD)
new_CnD = new_CnD.select(sorted(df_column_order))

lower_final_df = CmD_union_DmC.union(new_CnD)

result_df_lower = D_minus_C.union(lower_new_df)

df_result_lower_seg = result_df_lower.union(new_CnD)


df_final_result .write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:system/oracle123@127.0.0.1:1010:orcl") \
    .option("dbtable", "mydata") \
    .option("user", "system") \
    .option("password", "oracle123") \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
    .save()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at [Spark UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) and monitoring guide
2. Try to split your job into steps. Then find the step that is failing.